# Fitting an image of two overlapping circles

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a 2D image of two overlapping circles, in which one of the circles consists entirely of ones and the other consists entirely of zeros. Below is a minimum working example.

curve_fit does not seem to do any fitting at all, just returns the initial guess. I've started out trying just to fit one parameter for one of the circles, but in the end, I'd like to fit all the parameters: positions of both circle centers and each circle's radius.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def overlapping_circles((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1):
    img = np.zeros_like(x)

    img[np.sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2) <= r0] = 1.
    img[np.sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2) <= r1] = 0.

    return img.ravel()

size = 100.
# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, size-1, size)
y = np.linspace(0, size-1, size)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x0, y0 = size/2., size/2.
r0 = 30.
x1, y1 = size/2., size/4.
r1 = 30.
img = overlapping_circles((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
plt.imshow(img.reshape(size, size), interpolation='none')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda (x,y), guess_x0: overlapping_circles((x,y), guess_x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1), (x, y), img, p0=x0/2.)
print(popt, x0/2.)
```

Overlapping circles:

[image: Overlapping circles]

---

Thanks to lucianopaz for a workable solution. I've pasted the code the implements the suggestion of using brute force below for posterity.

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import brute

def overlapping_circles((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1):
    img = np.zeros_like(x)

    img[np.sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2) <= r0] = 1.
    img[np.sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2) <= r1] = 0.

    return img.ravel()

def residuals((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1, img):
    return np.sum((overlapping_circles((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1) - img.ravel())**2.)

size = 100.
# Create x and y indices
x = np.linspace(0, size-1, size)
y = np.linspace(0, size-1, size)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
x0, y0 = size/2., size/2.
r0 = 30.
x1, y1 = size/2., size/4.
r1 = 30.
img = overlapping_circles((x, y), x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
plt.imshow(img.reshape(size, size), interpolation='none')

simplified_residuals = lambda fit_x0: residuals((x, y), fit_x0[0], fit_x0[1], r0, x1, y1, r1, img)

rranges = (slice(0, 100, 1), slice(0, 100, 1))
resbrute = brute(simplified_residuals, rranges, full_output=True, finish=None)
print(resbrute[0], x0, y0)
```

Comment: Pretty sure `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` is not even close to the right tool for this job. I don't think that funciton does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `curve_fit` is correct, with the only minor comment that I think that `x` and `y` should be ravel'ed and placed into an array because the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) say that the independent variable should be:

> An M-length sequence or an (k,M)-shaped array for functions with k predictors. The independent variable where the data is measured.

However, I believe that your problem does not lie there but it happens because the function `overlapping_circles` is poorly conditioned. It is not differentiable because small changes in the parameters may lead to no change in the img due to the pixel discretization of `img`. In order to improve the fits, you should use methods that do not use jacobians nor hessians of the minimized function, and that work well with poorly conditioned, non-differentiable problems. I recommend you take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping), [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) and [here](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaes_inmatlab.html). Of course, for your problem it may be usefull just to use a [brute force](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute) approach to get a rough estimate of the parameters.

Comment: Perfect! Your suggestion of using brute force worked. I've pasted the solution I used as an edit to my original question. Thanks.